# Convergence in law and continuity of limit implies uniform convergence of distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_n$ be a series of random variables converging in law to $X$. Let $F_n,F$ be the corresponding distribution functions, then if the variable $X$ is continuous (takes every value with probability 0) $F_n$ converges uniformly to $F$.

I know that convergence in law implies the convergence of $F_n$ to $F$ in every point where $F$ is continuous (here then in every point), but how can you prove that the convergence is uniform?

thank you!

Comment: After you asked this, it has been answered here [Convergence in law implies uniform convergence of cdf's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670030/convergence-in-law-implies-uniform-convergence-of-cdfs)