Convergence of sequence of CDF
Let $\{F_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow [0,1]\}_n$ be a sequence of cummulative distribution functions (all of them continuous functions). Let $\{x_n\}_n$ be a sequence or real numbers.
We know that $F_n(t)\rightarrow F(t)$ for every $t\in\mathbb R$, where $F$ is a continuous cummulative distribution function. We also know that $x_n$ converges to $x\in\mathbb R$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$.
The question is to prove whether or not
$$
F_n(x_n)\rightarrow F(x)
$$
My problem is that the subindices for the CDF's and the sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ are the same. My idea is that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_n(x_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}F_m(x_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}F(x_n) = F(x),
$$
where the last equality is due to the continuity of $F$. The first equality is my doubt.
Thanks in advance.

It is well known that $F_n \to F$ uniformly on $\mathbb  R$.  [Continuity of $F$ is all you need for this. Continuity of $F_n$'s is not needed].  If $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then $f_n(x_n) \to f(x)$ whenever $x_n \to x$. Any Calculus book will contain  a proof. Ref. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670030/convergence-in-law-implies-uniform-convergence-of-cdfs?rq=1
